# How to change the style properties in a div which is written inline style?

Tags: php, jquery

I have written a code for modifying the inline style for a div. The code is shown below :

```
         <div class="padd col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 pern alert" id="bloc" style="display:none;"> 
                            <div class="pad col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                                <h4>dfdfdffddf</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="pad col-md-5">
                                <span class="next-step"><button class="ret_but butt label label-primary" id="equipment" name="equipment" type="button">Select Equipment</button></span>
                                <div class="status">
                                    <b>Status</b>
                                    <i class="open" id="open">Open</i>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="pad col-xs-12 col-md-1">

                                <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button"> <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

I want to change the style for the div with id = bloc as display: block. I have written a jquery code for it, but it is not working.

jquery :

```
 $("#senddata").click(function() {


        $(".padd").css('style','display:block;');


});
```

senddata  is the id of a button inside a form.When I am clicking that button, the inline style of particular div should change to display:block. But it is not changing the style. Can anyone help me on this ?

Comment: it's `.css('display', 'block')` or `.attr('style', 'display: block')`. better the first option

Comment: But it is not working...

Answer (score 1):

`style` is not a valid style attribute. you need to change `display`

```
    $(".padd").css('display','block');
```

It does not matter if the style is written in the style attribute or in a css file when you want to change it with jquery

Answer (score 0):

your JQ is not correct . you could use the `show()` method instead

**[show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/)**

```js
 $("#senddata").click(function() {


        $(".padd").show()


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="senddata">
 senddata
 </button>
 
 <div class="padd col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 pern alert" id="bloc" style="display:none;"> 
                            <div class="pad col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                                <h4>dfdfdffddf</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="pad col-md-5">
                                <span class="next-step"><button class="ret_but butt label label-primary" id="equipment" name="equipment" type="button">Select Equipment</button></span>
                                <div class="status">
                                    <b>Status</b>
                                    <i class="open" id="open">Open</i>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="pad col-xs-12 col-md-1">

                                <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button"> <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have used `display:none` on inline style you have to use the `show()` and `hide()` methods in jQuery.

```
 $("#senddata").click(function() {
        $(".padd").show()
});
```